# li div Align Center - Bug Firefox

Tags: css, html, alignment, html-lists

Work in IE and Chrome, but in firefox broken align. Some one can help me? problem is in line ".menu_central .navegacao li". with out "border: 1px solid #000; width: 215px;" work but with not work.

i need align center in firefox.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <style>
            html { color: #000; background: #FFF; }
            body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td { margin : 0; padding : 0; }
            table { border-collapse : collapse; border-spacing : 0; }
            fieldset, img { border : 0; }
            address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var { font-style : normal; font-weight : normal; }
            li { list-style : none; }
            caption, th { text-align : left; }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-size : 100%; font-weight : normal; }
            q:before, q:after { content : ''; }
            abbr, acronym { border : 0; font-variant : normal; }
            sup { vertical-align: text-top; }
            sub { vertical-align: text-bottom; }
            input, textarea, select { font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; }
            legend { color : #000; }

            html, body {
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
            .menu_central {
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            }
            .menu_central .navegacao { 
                line-height: 30px;              
                text-align : center;                

                /* Firefox */   
                display: -webkit-box;
                -moz-box-pack: center;
                -moz-box-align: center;

                /* Safari and Chrome */
                display: -webkit-box;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -webkit-box-align: center;

                /* W3C */
                display: box;
                box-pack: center;
                box-align: center;

            }
            .menu_central .navegacao li { 
                border: 1px solid #000;
                width: 215px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu_central">
            <ul class="navegacao">
                <li><span class="inicial_nome">Q</span>uem Somos</li>
            </ul
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use `0px`.  That has as much meaning as `0brasileiros`.  Zero is zero! Just use `0`!

Comment: replace border: 1px solid #000 with outline: 1px solid #000; is a dirty fix but should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add display: inline-block.

So, your code should look like:

```
.menu_central .navegacao li { 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 215px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: ty man... the command display: inline-block worked. do you know why i need do this command only in firefox?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure 100%. It is very difficult to say what is a problem with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment

Replace:

```
border: 1px solid #000;
```

With:

```
outline: 1px solid #000;
```

This because, outlines do not take up space. So it should work for everybrowser. You may need to add 1px or 2px to the rest of your divs because the border is gone.

Comment: the problem is not related to the border. Refers to the center alignment. srdjan answered my question.. ty for you help... I did not know his command also.